# Macro runs perfectly on personal computer, but encounters "application-defined or object-oriented error" in remote desktop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few macros in a ~10mb excel workbook. This macro works perfectly with no errors on my personal computer. However, when I open it in my remote desktop and run it from there I get an "application or object-defined error". It highlights a simple line of code that works perfectly outside of the remote environment:

```
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(54,1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=Cor_Matrices2!R1C1:R41C20"
```

The last line gets highlighted.
Cor_Matrices2 is a sheet in the workbook, though if it wasn't I would imagine the code would still run but return #ref

The excel version on my personal computer is Microsoft 365 apps for enterprise version 2008
The excel version on my remote desktop is Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus version 1908

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Your version 1908 does not have dynamic array formulas.

Answer (score 2):

`Range.Formula2R1C1` uses the dynamic array formulas and as such if the target computer does not have the dynamic array formula it will not work.

We can do something different.

```
With ActiveSheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cor_Matrices2").Range("A1:T20").Copy
    .Cells(54,1).Select
    .PasteSpecial Link:=True
End With
```